# How to check start and end time of a process in windows (c#)

Tags: c#, windows, process

Lets say I have an application (notepad.exe) which is supposed to be monitor like when it has been opened and closed.

To achieve this task can we take a help of process, when process started, point that time and also note for end time of the particular process.

I have looked msdn link but it shows only how to start and stop manually. I want to monitor the process which has started already by the system or manually.
Ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z4t818a(v=vs.90).aspx

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the `Process` class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx). It has StartTime and EndTime properties.

Comment: I don't want to start and stop it but I want to monitor (timings of) particular process which has been started by some one else.

Comment: Consider using the [Stopwatch Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)? Start the stopwatch at the beginning of a process and stop it at the end and log the time.

Comment: @ARJUN When did I say anything about starting or stopping it? Did you see all of the `GetProcess*()` methods?

Comment: [This gives you pretty much a step by step tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI) of how to do it using WMI. In fact the article even uses notepad.exe as a example program to monitor